# Using While Loop in SQL Query -Its keep inserting the record without break

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, loops, while-loop

Im using while loop to move incremental data from old table to new tables after i change the identity column from INT to BigInt. i have restored 1 billion of records . But still there is incremental data that i need to move into new table.Im currently working on inserting the incremental data from old table to new table. Hence i have taken the max(hist_id) from staging tables and configure that as parameter value in parameter table as @hist_id_start. The batch will run 100k once. Hence it will look for the hist_id from old table and insert till all the new records getting inserted into new table. The below query doesn't seems working . For example hist_id start is 6709 and it should insert 1000 records into batches and stop once its reach 13218 but somehow its keep looping and inserting unwanted records.
This is sample record : it start with 6709 and i add 1000 records 7709 and it should insert till it reach 13218
**hist_id_start: 6709
hist_id_end: 7709
Record count: 1000
hist_id_max: 13218**

```
DECLARE @hist_id_start INT;
DECLARE @hist_id_end INT;
DECLARE @hist_id_max INT;
DECLARE @batchcount INT;
DECLARE @reccount INT;

SET @batchcount =1000
SELECT @hist_id_start = value_text from PARAMETER (NOLOCK) WHERE PARAMETER_NAME='DIST_PRODUCT_COST_HIST_ID_INCREMENTAL'
SET @hist_id_end= (@hist_id_start + @batchcount)

set @hist_id_max= (select max(hist_id) from DIST_PRODUCT_COST_HIST with(nolock))

SELECT @reccount = count(*) from dist_product_cost_hist (nolock)  WHERE hist_id >=@hist_id_start and hist_id < (@hist_id_end)

PRINT 'hist_id_start: ' + convert(nvarchar(20), @hist_id_start)
PRINT 'hist_id_end: ' + convert(nvarchar(20), @hist_id_end)
PRINT 'Record count: ' + convert(nvarchar(20),  @reccount)
PRINT 'hist_id_max: ' + convert(nvarchar(20),  @hist_id_max)

while(@hist_id_end=<@hist_id_max)
--select IDENT_CURRENT('dist_product_cost_hist')   - number need to always less than SELECT value_text from PARAMETER (NOLOCK) WHERE PARAMETER_NAME='DIST_PRODUCT_COST_HIST_ID'

begin 
INSERT INTO Dist_Product_Cost_Hist_2022(dist_id,dist_sku_num,cost_type_code,cost_ref_num,cost,eff_date,end_date,manual_flag,currency_code,update_dts,update_uid,row_id)
SELECT dist_id,dist_sku_num,cost_type_code,cost_ref_num,cost,eff_date,end_date,manual_flag,currency_code,update_dts,update_uid,row_id
FROM Dist_Product_Cost_Hist (nolock)
WHERE hist_id >=@hist_id_start and hist_id < (@hist_id_end)


-- Update last hist_id in parameter table
UPDATE PARAMETER
set value_text=@hist_id_end, update_dts =getdate()
WHERE PARAMETER_NAME='DIST_PRODUCT_COST_HIST_ID_INCREMENTAL'
end
```

Comment: What does *"doesn't seems working"* mean? Are you getting an error? Unexpected results? Undesired behaviour? A Server Crash? A fire starts in your server room? We can't help you if we don't know what the actual problem is.

Comment: @larnu the hist_id start 6709 and it should insert 1000 records into batches and stop once it reach 13218 but somehow its keep looping and the result not getting inserted correctly

Comment: As far as I can tell, you aren't changing the value of `@hist_id_end` or `@hist_id_start` in your loop, so you';re going to `SELECT` the *same* rows over and over and over... and over... and over again. Also, why are you using `NOLOCK` against `Dist_Product_Cost_Hist`? It's really not a good idea to use that hint if you are needing to migrate **accurate** data. [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: @larnu where and how  should i use the value of hist_id _end and hist_id_start

Comment: You are already using them: `WHERE hist_id >=@hist_id_start and hist_id < (@hist_id_end)` The problem is that for each loop the values of said variables are **the same**. If very single terms you have `DECLARE @i int = 1, @t int = 10; WHILE @i < @t BEGIN PRINT @i END;` That loop will *forever* `PRINT` the value `1`.

Comment: Why have you now tagged [[tag:MySQL]]? Have you changed what product you are using? The above is clearly T-SQL and won't work on MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increment @hist_id_end after every iteration:

```
while(@hist_id_end=<@hist_id_max)
--select IDENT_CURRENT('dist_product_cost_hist')   - number need to always less than SELECT value_text from PARAMETER (NOLOCK) WHERE PARAMETER_NAME='DIST_PRODUCT_COST_HIST_ID'

begin 
INSERT INTO Dist_Product_Cost_Hist_2022(dist_id,dist_sku_num,cost_type_code,cost_ref_num,cost,eff_date,end_date,manual_flag,currency_code,update_dts,update_uid,row_id)
SELECT dist_id,dist_sku_num,cost_type_code,cost_ref_num,cost,eff_date,end_date,manual_flag,currency_code,update_dts,update_uid,row_id
FROM Dist_Product_Cost_Hist (nolock)
WHERE hist_id >=@hist_id_start and hist_id < (@hist_id_end)

-- Update last hist_id in parameter table
UPDATE PARAMETER
set value_text=@hist_id_end, update_dts =getdate()
WHERE PARAMETER_NAME='DIST_PRODUCT_COST_HIST_ID_INCREMENTAL'

SET @hist_id_end = @hist_id_end + @batchcount

end
```

Comment: if i add the hist_id end its keep looping too as below .